# vagrant homestead - public network not working on osx

Tags: macos, vagrant, virtualbox

I've been trying all day to get a public network setup using Vagrant 1.6.5 with VirtualBox. I really need to be able to access all my Homestead sites on my other devices (iPad, iPhone, Android phone, etc.) on my local network. The box provisions fine but the sites all timeout.

**homestead.rb**

```
config.vm.network "public_network", :bridge => "en0: Wi-Fi (AirPort)", :ip => "192.168.1.200"
```

My host is OS X mavericks using DHCP (`192.168.1.137`).

Private networking works fine, but I can't get public networking to work with any variation of the above config.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm running into the same issue at the moment.

Comment: Nope, I gave up on this...sorry :/

Comment: No worries. If I find a solution I'll let you know

Comment: I got it working, really easy, see my answer, or let me know if it's still not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just grab the host's internal IP address (**NOT the VM ip**) and add the port `:8000`. Let's say your host ip is 192.168.0.5, then from any other device on your network, you can just browse to the host at `192.168.0.5:8000` and you'll hit the VM and see the Laravel home page.

This works great for me with the default homestead.rb setting:

```
# Configure A Private Network IP
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: settings["ip"] ||= "192.168.10.10"
```

Comment: Simple solution for me ended up being assigning each site a unique port at the server block level. Then just doing a vagrant share with the port.

Answer (score 3):

To get my homestead machine to be visible from my LAN I did the following:

1. Edit the `Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb` file and set `config.vm.network :public_network, ip: "192.168.1.123"` (just make sure the IP is free).
2. Do a `vagrant reload`
3. Make sure my old local `hosts` file now points to the new IP.

The result is I can ping `192.168.1.123` from another machine in my LAN.

Comment: As a note, this seems to break my Xdebug (breakpoints are only hit one time, then execution jumps to a different place), for which I haven't yet found a fix.

Answer (score 0):

What is the error that you are getting? Make sure that 192.168.1.200 is not being used by any other device.

[Network configuration for vagrant boxes](http://www.brownfort.com/2014/09/network-configuration-vagrant-boxes/)

Comment: I don't get an error, the box starts up without a hitch however any attempts to access the sites in the browser ultimately time out. I have triple-checked there are no other devices using that IP address.

Answer (score -1):

This row works fine for me:

```
config.vm.network :public_network, ip: settings["ip"] ||= "192.168.10.10", bridge: "eth0"
```

Then it uses the ip variable from ~/.homstead/Homestead.yaml and if thats not set it uses 192.168.10.10